# how to concatinate the array with the serialized data, jquery, ajax

Tags: jquery

I had an 'notesAttachments' array in which i had three files and each file contains filename, originalfilename. and i had created a 'values' array and added each item to this array.

```
 var values = new Array();

     for (var item = 0; item < notesAttachments.length; item++) {


        var noteAttachmentObj = {};


        noteAttachmentObj.FileName == notesAttachments[item].FileName;
        noteAttachmentObj.OriginalFileName = notesAttachments[item].OriginalFileName;

        values.push(noteAttachmentObj);

        }
```

and i want to add this 'values' array to the serailized data something like

```
 var serializedFormser = $("#updatenotes").serialize();
```

here 'updatenotes' is the form id. I want to attach the 'values' collection to this 'serializedFormser'.  I had tried a lot but i could not. Can any one please tell me the solution...

any i am using this serialized to my ajax call..

Answer (score 0):

```
var serializedFormser = $("#updatenotes").serialize();
for (var item = 0; item < notesAttachments.length; item++) {
    serializedFormser+= "&fname"+item+"="+notesAttachments[item].FileName;
    serializedFormser+= "&ofname"+item+"="+notesAttachments[item].OriginalFileName;
    } serializedFormser+="&count="+item;
```

then you should use for loop. from 0 to count variable.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But the filename and orignalfilename is in BO some thing like   public List<ClaimDocumentBO> notesAttachments { get; set; }.  So the concatinated array should assign to this collection i.e notesAttachments.